# Excel Drop Down in Shared Mode

Tags: excel

When I change my excel workbook to shared mode and try to copy and paste rows that have drop down lists (Data validation List), the drop down disappears.

It works fine as long as the workbook is not shared.  Any solutions?

Comment: It doesn't work for someone else when you share it or for you?

Comment: Both when it's in shared mode.  I need to share the workbook with my team to work in it simultaneously

Comment: Well my idea was that when you share it the source of the data in the drop down might be only on your computer hence when someone else tries to open it on their machines can't populate the drop downs. But since it doesn't work for everyone...

Comment: Any workarounds.  to this issue?  Drop Down allows everyone to organize the data in a more standardized way otherwise, everyone just uses different ways to say the same thing

Comment: Is everyone using the same version of Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Set the Workbook to unshared, copypasta your data and then share the workbook again.

Shared workbooks [are useful](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61), regardless of their (many) limitations. In a shared workbook, you cannot:

- Create an Excel table
- Insert or delete blocks of cells
- Delete worksheets
- Merge cells or split merged cells
- Add or change conditional formats
- Add or change data validation
- Create or change charts or PivotChart reports
- Insert or change pictures or other objects
- Insert or change hyperlinks
- Use drawing tools
- Assign, change, or remove passwords
- Protect or unprotect worksheets or the workbook
- Create, change, or view scenarios
- Group or outline data
- Insert automatic subtotals
- Create data tables
- Create or change PivotTable reports
- Write, record, change, view, or assign macros
- Change or delete array formulas
- Use a data form to add new data
- Work with XML data

Before you unshare the workbook, ensure no-one else is using it by clicking Share Workbook in the Changes group on the Review tab.

Select the name of the user who you want to disconnect, and then click Remove User.

Answer (score 0):

Shared workbooks have severe limitations. Some functionality is disabled in shared workbooks. Other stuff just slowly starts to fall apart.

Consensus amongst Excel experts is that shared workbooks should be avoided, because it's not a quesiton of IF but WHEN they will become corrupt. Shared workbooks are impossible to troubleshoot.

Yes, Excel offers the feature, but it was never designed for simultaneous multi-user write access to a data set. If you need that functionality, you'd be better off with a database like Access or SQL.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and searched to find that there is no scope to add drop-down to the shared workbook. I got my work done by simply removing share option in the workbook, applied desired changes and shared the workbook again. :)